# SQL Server certificate for backups: Does expiration date matter?

Tags: sql-server, backup, certificate

If I have a cert in SQL Server, used for backups:

1. Can backups still be created after cert expires?
2. Can restore still happen after cert expires?

What is the point of having these certs expire? (other than to expose me to backups failing due to expired cert...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have tested this on SQL Server 2016 (Developer Edition, though that shouldn't matter), and can confirm:

1. No, after the Certificate expires, using it to encrypt a backup will cause the following error:

   > Msg 3096, Level 16, State 1, Line xx
   >   The Certificate specified for backup encryption has expired.
   >   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line xx
   >   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
2. Yes, after a Certificate expires, backups encrypted from that Certificate can still be restored. BUT, you still need to have the Certificate loaded into `master` in order to do the `RESTORE`.

Just create a new Certificate, and be sure to specify the `EXPIRY_DATE = 'utc_date'` clause, else the expiration date will default to 1 year from the moment it was created.

As to why Certificates have expiration dates, that is probably to give more control over the security mechanism, similar to how you can set a password policy for Logins to expire. Certificates can be backed-up and used in multiple places, so it can help ensure that you don't have a piece of information sitting out there, somewhere, forever that can be used to compromise your system.

Comment: This has to be tested out - pretty sure in TDE it does not matter, but for mirroring and backups it [might matter and will cause failures](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/134642/change-certificate-expiration.html)